# tkinter code after mainloop() not being executed after closing window

Tags: python, class, tkinter, mainloop

I need help using tkinter in python.
I want to use a while loop inside my class so that it keeps printing in the terminal the content of an entry (`box1`). But the problem is that if I put a loop in my class the entry wont even be created because the `root.mainloop()` is after my while loop.

The program:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(root, self).__init__()
        
        self.minsize(500,400)
        self.configure(bg='#121213')

        self.createEntry()


    def createEntry(self):
        self.name1 = StringVar()
        self.box1 = ttk.Entry(self, width=2, textvariable = self.name1, font="Calibri 15")
        self.box1.place(x=128, y=31)
        while True:
            print(self.name1.get())


        
root=root()
root.mainloop()
```

If I put the loop after the `root.mainloop()` it won't start printing the contents of `name1` as long as the tkinter file is open. So it will print only the final version of `name1` in a loop:
The Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(root, self).__init__()
        
        self.minsize(500,400)
        self.configure(bg='#121213')

        self.createEntry()


    def createEntry(self):
        self.name1 = StringVar()
        self.box1 = ttk.Entry(self, width=2, textvariable = self.name1, font="Calibri 15")
        self.box1.place(x=128, y=31)
        while True:
            print(self.name1.get())


        
root=root()
root.mainloop()
while True:
    print(root.name1.get())
```

[Video of my problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IY5hckmPkwjlosqRUNGFpYXsx0leh83z/view?usp=sharing)

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a solution that does not put constant drain on the processing power?
If you add a callback to StringVar, you can trigger a function every time the variable is changed, and only then. Infinite loops don't work very well with UI applications, as in order to avoid stopping the control flow of the app you have to use things like async, threading etc.

```
    def createEntry(self):
        self.name1 = StringVar()
        self.name1.trace_add("write", lambda name, index, mode: print(self.name1.get()))
        self.box1 = ttk.Entry(self, width=2, textvariable = self.name1, font="Calibri 15")
        self.box1.place(x=128, y=31)
```

This piece of code will make given lambda function trigger every time something is written to `name1` variable.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed

Comment: is it possible to have 2 modes, I want to  execute `print(self.name1.get())` and another command whenever I type something in the `box1`

Comment: @TheFishy You can define normal function that accepts `name, index, mode` arguments instead of the lambda one and do whatever you need in this function.

Comment: I still have one question, I know it's not the right place to ask it but I'm not finding a better one.

I want to get the name of the variable the focus is on so I'm using the `focus_get()` function. But the problem is that this function is returning the type of widget that the focus is on, for example: `.!radiobutton`, `.!entry` or `.!button`. This doesn't tell me which radiobutton, entry or button the focus is on, it just tells me that the focus is on _**a**_ radiobutton, entry or button.

How could I know specifically on which variable the focus is on?

Comment: @TheFishy better place would be a separate question. But I'm gonna answer anyway - it **does** actually tell you which specific element the focus is on. You can easily verify that by adding two elements of the same kind - you will notice that one will be called e.g. "button" and the other "button2". It is name internally assigned by Tkinter and you can get that name by using `.winfo_name()` on the widget object, and conversely do `master.nametowidget()` to get the widget object by its name.